# SQL Как определить уникального пользователя?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*Добрый день обучение по SQl
Три задания по номерам в результате 1 запрос.
Со 2 номера не знаю как реализовать.*

1)Придумать запрос для подсчёта ТОП 10 фильмов по колл-во уникальных пользователей, группировка по месяцам. 
2)Рассчитать динамику в процентах от месяца к месяцу для фильмов из top10. 
3)Для фильмов, которые пришли в ТОП 10 первый раз считать, что в предыдущем месяце у них не было показов.

Пример результата

```
Текущий месяц; позиция в top10;название; количество уникальных пользователей; разница с прошлым месяцем
2017-05-01;1;Маша и медведь: Первая встреча;10000;-10.1%
2017-05-01;2;Маша и медведь: До весны не будить;5000;1.3%

сontent - фильмы (контент)
content_id integer,
title varchar
сontent_watch - показы контента
watch_id varchar - уникальный идентификатор показа
content_id integer- id контента
show_date timestamp - дата и время показа
user_id integer - уникальный идентификатор пользователя
сalendar - справочник дат с 1900 по 2100 год по дням
date timestamp
```

*Реализую на диалекте mssql.
1 и 2 номер выполнил, как 3 не понимаю.*

```
SELECT A.RAN, A.DATE,A.MODEL,A.COUNT_ID,
CONVERT(FLOAT(1),(FIRST_VALUE(A.COUNT_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY A.RAN ORDER BY A.RAN)-LEAD(A.COUNT_ID,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY A.RAN))/LEAD(A.COUNT_ID,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY A.RAN)*100) AS DINAMIC 
FROM (SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Month(DATE) ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC)AS RAN, Month(DATE) AS DATE , user_id,COUNT(user_id)AS COUNT_ID 
FROM PC GROUP BY Month(DATE), user_id ORDER BY RAN OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY) AS A
```

Comment: Учитывая, что требуется разница с предыдущим месяцем, надо получить сначала значения каждого месяца, а потом воспользоваться функцией LAG() что бы получить значение из предыдущей строки для сравнения

Comment: Mike, последняя модификация в моём запросе содержит отсортированное процентное соотношение. Как мне при помощи функции LAG()  вычесть из 2 строки 1, сответственно, из 3 строки вычесть 2 ?

Comment: так как вы уже использовали оконные функции, то дайте имена колонкам, оберните запрос в еще один запрос и на верхнем уровне уже делайте спокойно `x-lag(x) over(order by date partition by фильм)`

Comment: Mike, спасибо, разобрался со 2 номером, поправил код. Не подскажите с 3 номером , про условие "Не было показов". Я думаю, это Where внутри под запроса но как его реализовать ?

Comment: lead в первой строке окна обычно возвращает NULL, так как как не было еще значений. Думаю под 3 пунктом понимается, что надо в этом случае счиатать предыдущее значение 0, а не NULL. Чего можно достичь, обернув lead в coalesce или использовав значение по умолчанию, которое можно передать третьим параметром lead

Comment: @Mike у функции Lead можно указать значение по умолчанию для возвращаемого значения, если текущая строка в окне последняя, плюс мне кажется в своем комментарии вы перепутали Lead с Lag, последняя как раз возвращает NULL для первой строки, если не указано значение по умолчанию

Comment: Serge Nazarenko, добрый день, во что можно обернуть это выражение, что бы не было ошибки из-за деления на ноль ?